# How to launch a google-chrome pop-up window using command?

Tags: command-line, google-chrome, launcher

My preferred browser is Firefox and I don't like using Chrome, but Netflix only works within Chrome on Linux. Instead of starting Chrome I made a small launcher that uses the following command:

```
google-chrome --kiosk www.netflix.com
```

I launch chrome in the Kiosk mode, which means it's permanently full-screen.

I'm wondering if I can get it to launch in Chrome's pop-up window using a different tag so I can F11 out of full-screen mode and close it with my cursor instead of Alt+F4. I know I can use the following command to maximize the window:

```
google-chrome --start-maximized www.netflix.com
```

But then it still uses the normal window.

Does anyone know the tag for launching in pop-up mode?

This is what the pop-up window looks like (Ignore the second screen): [Pop-Up Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mah7s.png)

Thanks!

Siarl

Comment: I guess you need to run `google-chrome --app=URL`

Comment: @MostafaAhangarha This launches a normal Chrome window and an "app" window for me. Does this happen to you too?

Comment: No. It should just open in app mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First load Netflix into Google Chrome.  Then (click) **File** -> (Click) **Create Application Short Cut** -> (Click ) **Create**.

**Now you will have a Netflix launcher Ubuntu Dash Search.**

The Netflix that you launch will resemble the popup you have in your linked image.

**The commandline:**

```
$ google-chrome --app=https://www.netflix.com/browse
```

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I want. I now use `$ google-chrome  --start-fullscreen   --app=https://www.netflix.com/browse  ` I had tried --app before but without https:// so it didn't work.